# How to execute a program from a php web page?

Tags: php, ssh, exec, sudo

### Summary

I have apache running on a Linux machine where a certain program is installed. I want to call the program from a php page and get the output.

### Special constraint

The program needs certain environment variables to run, e.g. LD_LIBRARY_PATH with path to libraries plus extra variables. The environment is defined for a user *X* on the machine that is not the *apache* user.

### Proposed options

So far I have thought of the following options (not meaning that they are all smart or safe):

1. Allow user *apache* to run the program as user *X* (in a way that allows having the full environment). Recipe ?
2. Modify the environment of user *apache*. I don't see how because apache is a *nologin* user.
3. SSH to another machine as a user that has the proper environment. It means to have a no password (public/private keys) connection between the web server and this machine. Is it dangerous ?

### Questions

- Did I overlook a simpler or better option ?
- What option would you use and why ?

Comment: 2. sounds like the best option, I don't know how to do that though - but surely it is possible to set environment variables for the user on startup? Would that be enough?

Comment: Yes, it would be enough although the other user is already set up in a standard way therefore I would prefer to reuse it. If I have to do that I could also pass the environment variables when calling the program in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

if you know the (values of) environment variables you need to set, you could simply prepend them to your exec

```
exec('LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/you/paths"; OTHER_VAR="baz"; /your/bin');
```

that will execute `/your/bin` with the given ENV variables set, but as the apache user, not user *X*. If the program needs to run as a specific user, SSH doesn't seem like such a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have full control over this platform?

You can look into [suexec](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/suexec.html), or [mpm-iTK](http://mpm-itk.sesse.net)

You could configure the above within a virtual host, and set the run as user or group to that which has access to your binary.

In your current setup, you could create a new group, assign the apache user/group to said group, apply group to the binary you want to execute with read/write or read/execute permissions, and let the good times role.